# How to display a name instead of email address with django send_mail?

Tags: django, email

I want a name to appear instead of an email address when the user receives an email that is sent from django `send_mail()`.

For example:

When an email is sent with the below code the person who receives it sees `to@ex.com` in his inbox. I would like a name to be displayed.

```
send_mail('subject', 'content', from@ex.com, ['to@ex.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Just like when companies send their emails to users, we dont see an email address instead we see the company name.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using a [display name](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-16):

```
send_mail('subject', 'content', 'Name <from@ex.com>', ['to@ex.com'], fail_silently=False)
```